# Calling ShowDialog changes culture (locale)

Tags: c#, dialog, culture

While calling a simple .Net form (FolderBrowserDialog), it turns out the culture is changed without notice following a call to ShowDialog():

```
string ChooseFolder(ref string sTitle, string sCurDir)
{
    string folderPath = sCurDir;

    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    //folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    //folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = sCurDir;
    //folderBrowserDialog1.Description = sTitle;

    string str1 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    string str2;

    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        str2 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }

    string str3 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    return folderPath;
}
```

To be specific: while str1 shows my current locale (non-US) - str2 and str3 show the "en-US" locale. That's in the main thread, and I didn't found anything else that might affect it.

Will be glad to hear your ideas :)

Comment: Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to disable the shell extension that causes this problem.

Comment: it actually was a shell extension I recently installed (a cloud sync application). Thanks very much!